# When does JP2Launcher.exe hangs

Tags: java, applet

I am testing a JAVA Applet based application which hung in between and culprit was found to be JP2Launcher. Dev Team is asking to replicate the scenario and am not sure what actions are required to hang JP2Launcher.exe.

I already tried to go to task manager and stop it, but it kills the applet. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This is obsolete now... But still it was observed that memory full causes this issue... Increasing heap resolved this for me..